# How do I limit voucher's binding per transaction in Prestashop

Tags: bind, prestashop, cart

One of the prestashop's feature in cart pricing rules is the ability to bind different vouchers in one transaction. By default, you can bind 20 vouchers on a single transaction.

The question is: How do I limit the vouchers per transaction as 10 vouchers only?

Do I need to customize the code in backend or there's an option in prestahop's admin panel?

Hoping for your immediate response.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to override the ParentOrderController class, in this way:

```
<?php
class ParentOrderController extends ParentOrderControllerCore {
    public function init()
    {
        $this->isLogged = (bool)($this->context->customer->id && Customer::customerIdExistsStatic((int)$this->context->cookie->id_customer));

        FrontController::init();

        /* Disable some cache related bugs on the cart/order */
        header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
        header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');

        $this->nbProducts = $this->context->cart->nbProducts();

        if (!$this->context->customer->isLogged(true) && $this->useMobileTheme() && Tools::getValue('step'))
            Tools::redirect($this->context->link->getPageLink('authentication', true, (int)$this->context->language->id));

        // Redirect to the good order process
        if (Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE') == 0 && Dispatcher::getInstance()->getController() != 'order')
            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order');

        if (Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE') == 1 && Dispatcher::getInstance()->getController() != 'orderopc')
        {
            if (Tools::getIsset('step') && Tools::getValue('step') == 3)
                Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order-opc&isPaymentStep=true');
            Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order-opc');
        }

        if (Configuration::get('PS_CATALOG_MODE'))
            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('This store has not accepted your new order.');

        if (Tools::isSubmit('submitReorder') && $id_order = (int)Tools::getValue('id_order'))
        {
            $oldCart = new Cart(Order::getCartIdStatic($id_order, $this->context->customer->id));
            $duplication = $oldCart->duplicate();
            if (!$duplication || !Validate::isLoadedObject($duplication['cart']))
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Sorry. We cannot renew your order.');
            else if (!$duplication['success'])
                $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('Some items are no longer available, and we are unable to renew your order.');
            else
            {
                $this->context->cookie->id_cart = $duplication['cart']->id;
                $this->context->cookie->write();
                if (Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE') == 1)
                    Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order-opc');
                Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order');
            }
        }

        if ($this->nbProducts)
        {
            if (CartRule::isFeatureActive())
            {
                if (Tools::isSubmit('submitAddDiscount'))
                {
                    $cart_rules = $this->context->cart->getCartRules();

                    if (!($code = trim(Tools::getValue('discount_name'))))
                        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('You must enter a voucher code.');
                    elseif (!Validate::isCleanHtml($code))
                        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('The voucher code is invalid.');
                    elseif(count($cart_rules)>=10)
                        $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('You have reached the maximum number of coupons that can be used');
                    else
                    {
                        if (($cartRule = new CartRule(CartRule::getIdByCode($code))) && Validate::isLoadedObject($cartRule))
                        {
                            if ($error = $cartRule->checkValidity($this->context, false, true))
                                $this->errors[] = $error;
                            else
                            {
                                $this->context->cart->addCartRule($cartRule->id);
                                if (Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE') == 1)
                                    Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order-opc&addingCartRule=1');
                                Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order&addingCartRule=1');
                            }
                        }
                        else
                            $this->errors[] = Tools::displayError('This voucher does not exists.');
                    }
                    $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
                        'errors' => $this->errors,
                        'discount_name' => Tools::safeOutput($code)
                    ));
                }
                elseif (($id_cart_rule = (int)Tools::getValue('deleteDiscount')) && Validate::isUnsignedId($id_cart_rule))
                {
                    $this->context->cart->removeCartRule($id_cart_rule);
                    Tools::redirect('index.php?controller=order-opc');
                }
            }
            /* Is there only virtual product in cart */
            if ($isVirtualCart = $this->context->cart->isVirtualCart())
                $this->setNoCarrier();
        }

        $this->context->smarty->assign('back', Tools::safeOutput(Tools::getValue('back')));
    }
}
```

This is all the init() method, I have paste full to avoid mistake or errors.

Difference:

- Line #7 - Call FrontController::init() instead of parent::init()
- Line #56 - Get the current cart rules stored
- Line #62-63 - Here your request, check the numbers of cart rules

Pay attention if you upgrade your ps version, remember that you have overwritten the entire method.

Enjoy ;)